# Use Objects before they are created

Tags: java, user-interface, object

My question is if it is possible to use objects before the objects are created.
In my case, I have a GUI whit three panel's and I want to switch between them with buttons (I set one visible and the other invisible) so that only one panel is visible. Now my problem is that I can switch on one side, but not back.

[image: My Component order]

In this image, you can see what I mean. I start at PanelMain and there I have two buttons to switch to the two other panels, but if I'm eg now at PanelUni I can't make PanelMain visible because at this point of the code PanelMain does not exist.
Now my question is if the is a way to solve that problem.(and if I can use this also at variables and other objects)

Comment: How can you use something before it exists?

Comment: that is the problem :/

Comment: Using and object before it is created is impossible like it would be to answer a question befor it has been asked. But your actual problem (Not beeing able to switch back panels) could most likely be solved without any voodoo if you supplied an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as code and asked about the actual problem you are facing instead of an impossible proposed solution.

Comment: So create the object and then use it -- problem solved. I'm not sure what your exact question is?

Comment: You actually can use an object before it is fully constructed (i.e. 'exists') within the constructor. A common pitfall is to call overridable methods from the constructor, which implementation (in a subclass for example) could depend on initialization that has not been completed yet. But I think this topic is not the issue here. OP might not fully understand the difference between visibility in the UI and existance of an object instance.

Comment: There is no "chicken or egg comes first" problem here. Instantiate all 3 panel before using them or just instantiate it when you need to switch to that particular panel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). With a global [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) for your buttons you can then switch the content corresponding to the clicked button.